# Simpler way to ignore cases in python?

Tags: python

```
for wclass in word_class_dict[most_ambigious_word]:
    for sent in brown_sents:
        if (most_ambigious_word.capitalize(), wclass) in sent or (most_ambigious_word.upper(), wclass) in sent or (most_ambigious_word.lower(), wclass) in sent:
            print most_ambigious_word,"-",wclass
            print " ".join(tuple[0] for tuple in sent)
            break
```

To clarify `brown_sents` is a list of tuples, which cannot be changed. As for the simplifying bit, I find the 3 different checks a bit awkward to write. Any ideas?

Edit (for those interested in what the assignment task is) : 
The brown_sents is a list of tuples, which contain elements like :

```
[('word1' , 'wordclass1') , ('word2' , 'wordclass2') , ('word3' , 'wordclass2') ....]
```

So, I'm looking for say `word1` but the case should not matter. I.e : `word1` is the same as `Word1` and `wOrd1` for instance. `wclass` is wordclass, so I only want to print out sentences containing distinct pairs of `word1,wclass` (obviously, if word1 has multiple wordclasses, I want to loop through the wordclasses and print out one example for all of them, this is the outermost for loop).

Comment: I must also say that your whole loop looks kind of strange, what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for wclass in word_class_dict[most_ambigious_word]:
    for sent in brown_sents:
        if (most_ambigious_word.lower(), wclass) in ((word[0].lower(),word[1]) for word in sent) :
            print most_ambigious_word,"-",wclass
            print " ".join(tuple[0] for tuple in sent)
            break
```

This was actually all that was needed.

Comment: 1. you should call `most_ambigious_word.lower()` outside the loops. 2. `sent` is a tuple e.g., `('word1' , 'wordclass1')` so you could `if (most_ambigious_word, wclass) == sent:` (assuming that what you have said: "brown_sents is a list of tuples" is true.

Comment: I don't really have a most_ambigious_word variable, it's just the input to a function (I'm trying to keep it FP)

Answer (score 2):

If you search for multiple words it make sense to create a set:

```
print(set(brown_sents).intersection(zip(repeat(most_ambiguous_word),
                                        word_class_dict[most_ambiguous_word])))
```

#### [Example](http://ideone.com/au70x)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from itertools import repeat

word_class_dict = dict(word2=['wordclass1', 'wordclass2', 'wordclass3', 'wc5'])
brown_sents = [
    ('word1', 'wordclass1'),
    ('word2', 'wordclass2'),
    ('word3', 'wordclass2'),
    ('word2', 'wordclass3'),
    ('word2', 'wordclass4'),
]

most_ambiguous_word = 'Word2'

# search in `brown_sents` for `most_ambiguous_word`
# ignoring Unicode case-folding
most_ambiguous_word = most_ambiguous_word.lower()
print(set(brown_sents).intersection(zip(repeat(most_ambiguous_word),
                                        word_class_dict[most_ambiguous_word])))
```

#### Output

```
{('word2', 'wordclass2'), ('word2', 'wordclass3')}
```

To understand what it does, save the script to a file e.g., `search-word.py` and run:

```
$ python -i search-word.py
```

It shows the Python prompt:

```
>>>
```

You can try individual expressions to see what they do e.g.:

```
>>> zip(repeat('a'), [1,2,3])
[('a', 1), ('a', 2), ('a', 3)]
>>> set('abcaadeff')
set(['a', 'c', 'b', 'e', 'd', 'f'])
>>> set('abcaadeff').intersection('abc')
set(['a', 'c', 'b'])
```

To see help:

```
>>> help(zip)
Help on built-in function zip in module __builtin__:

zip(...)
    zip(seq1 [, seq2 [...]]) -> [(seq1[0], seq2[0] ...), (...)]

    Return a list of tuples, where each tuple contains the i-th element
    from each of the argument sequences.  The returned list is truncated
    in length to the length of the shortest argument sequence.
```

Press `q` to exit. If an individual help message is not clear:

```
>>> help(repeat)
Help on class repeat in module itertools:

class repeat(__builtin__.object)
 |  repeat(element [,times]) -> create an iterator which returns the element
 |  for the specified number of times.  If not specified, returns the element
 |  endlessly.
...[snip]...
```

try to see online help for the module:

```
>>> module = 'itertools'
>>> import webbrowser
>>> webbrowser.open('http://docs.python.org/library/' + module)
```

and find there [`itertools.repeat()`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools#itertools.repeat) function.

In short: read the docs, try some code at the prompt, repeat. If you are stuck, [ask question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: (+1) This seems to be what the OP should really do. *(Maybe it could be good to explain a bit that one line since the question is tagged as homework.)*

Comment: @Rik Poggi: I've added an explanation. Comments, hints?

Answer (score -1):

This should work:

```
if (most_ambigious_word.lower(), wclass) in (sent[0].lower(), sent[1]):
    # ...
```

Comment: `wclass` is a string in his example. Edit: It can also be a tuple, okay.